# Accessing DOM node using useState hook in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, emotion

```
const [contentRef, setContentRef] = useState<any>(null);

const doc = contentRef?.contentWindow?.document;
const mountNode = doc?.body;
const insertionTarget = doc?.head;

  return (
    <Box
      as="iframe"
      ref={setContentRef}
      {...props}
    >
      {* some code here *}
    </Box>
```

Recently while working with iframes and @emotion/react i came across this code but I am not sure about using useState for accessing DOM node.
when I console.log(contentRef) it returns iframe DOM node.

Can someone please explain how is this working and how it is different from using useRef().

Answer (score 0):

What you see there is a "[callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)".

> Instead of passing a ref attribute created by createRef(), you pass a
> function. The function receives the React component instance or HTML
> DOM element as its argument, which can be stored and accessed
> elsewhere.

`setContentRef` is a function that accepts the new state value. So the DOM node is passed to the `setState` call after its rendered. You will be able to access the DOM node in `contentRef` state.

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot!